# SQL query for returning nested categories in Google Cloud Spanner?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-spanner

I have the following table in Google Cloud Spanner for categories.

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  categoryId STRING(36) NOT NULL,
  name STRING(128) NOT NULL,
  parent BOOL NOT NULL,
  parentId STRING(36),
  archived BOOL,
  FOREIGN KEY (parentId) REFERENCES categories (categoryId)
) PRIMARY KEY(categoryId);
```

So the table might have entries as shown below.

| categoryId | name | parent | parentId | archived |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Clothing | true |  | false |
| 2 | Homeware | true |  | false |
| 3 | Shirts | false | 1 | false |
| 4 | Pants | false | 1 | false |
| 5 | Technology | true |  | false |
| 6 | Tablets | false | 5 | true |

I want to query this table such that it returns firstly all the parent categories that aren't archived (I can't really delete rows in my application, as documents will reference rows - so I implemented archiving), along with all the child categories (not archived) belonging to said parents.

I came as far as writing the following query:

```
SELECT categories.categoryId, categories.name, childCategories.name AS childName 
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN categories AS childCategories
ON childCategories.parentId = categories.categoryId
WHERE categories.parent = true AND categories.archived = FALSE
```

However, this will return rows where child categories are archived. Below is the exact result returned.

| categoryId | name | childName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Clothing | Shirts |
| 1 | Clothing | Pants |
| 2 | Homeware |  |
| 5 | Technology | Tablets |

The desired result would be:

| categoryId | name | childName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Clothing | Shirts |
| 1 | Clothing | Pants |
| 2 | Homeware |  |
| 5 | Technology |  |

I have tried altering the query as:

```
SELECT categories.categoryId, categories.name, childCategories.name AS childName 
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN categories AS childCategories
ON childCategories.parentId = categories.categoryId
WHERE categories.parent = true AND categories.archived = FALSE AND childCategories.archived = FALSE
```

This, however, won't return any parent categories if they don't have at least one child category. Below is the exact result returned.

| categoryId | name | childName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Clothing | Shirts |
| 1 | Clothing | Pants |

I can't figure out how to write the query to obtain the desired result. Any help/insight would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Almost there, Move this `childCategories.archived = FALSE` to the ON condition instead of Where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, as you need only the child Categories which are not archived, Move the condition `childCategories.archived = FALSE` to `ON`  instead of `WHERE` clause.

Putting the filter on `WHERE` will remove the result from Dataset, however if you put it in `ON` condition, will return everything from parent Categories and respective matching row from Child.

```
SELECT categories.categoryId, categories.name, childCategories.name AS childName 
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN categories AS childCategories
ON childCategories.parentId = categories.categoryId
AND childCategories.archived = FALSE --Added here
WHERE categories.parent = true AND categories.archived = FALSE
```